# Set filename as value in CMD?

Tags: filenames, cmd.exe

I want to create an option in the right click menu of files that'll get their file name. My problem in now this, how to set the file name as value in CMD?

I tried this:

```
    @echo off
    for /r %%f in (*.bat) do (
    set w=%%~nxf
    echo %w%
    )
    pause
```

But `w` is empty after run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, on my system there's an issue with your batch script which i'll describe, but I don't know why your w is empty after run, but if you remove @echo off you can see what is going on. and from this explanation, maybe we'll see why it's empty.  It must be the last setting of w is setting it to nothing.

```
    @echo off
    for /r %%f in (*.bat) do (
    set w=%%~nxf
    echo %w%
    )
    pause
```

There is an issue above, in that you are using `%...%` in a for loop and what happens with `%var%` in a for loop e.g. `%w%` in batch files, is very strange compared to any other language! The `%w%` will get replaced by whatever `%w%` is, and then not again after that.

You could try to test this by doing set w=abcdefg   then run your batch file and see if w is still that.

But on my machine, after it is running set `w=%%~nxf`   and then you have echo `%w%` that `%w%` there in the echo, is then set to the current value of `%%~nxf`,   which is your first bat file. And that's it. It stays that way.   It's not what you intend no doubt but that's what happens.

Here is your bat file I removed @echo off.

```
for /r %%f in (*.bat) do (
set w=%%~nxf
echo %w%
)
```

Here is the output showing what happens, which is what I described. The %w% keeps its first value.

```
C:\crp>spo <Return>

C:\crp>for /R %f in (*.bat) do (
set w=%~nxf
 echo spo2.bat
)

C:\crp>(
set w=a.bat
 echo spo2.bat
)
spo2.bat

C:\crp>(
set w=b.bat
 echo spo2.bat
)
spo2.bat

C:\crp>(
set w=spo.bat
 echo spo2.bat
)
spo2.bat

C:\crp>(
set w=spo2.bat
 echo spo2.bat
)
spo2.bat

C:\crp>
```

You need to add
setlocal ....  and replace %var% with !var! then you get normal behaviour!

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for /r %%f in (*.bat) do (
    set w=%%~nxf
    echo !w!
)


C:\crp>spo2
a.bat
b.bat
spo.bat
spo2.bat

C:\crp>
```

Comment: Thanks Barlop, last code you put worked, But I wonder that if I run my code,by double click on .bat file, it doesn't work! , but if run CMD and paste .bat file path in it and press Enter, it work! and echo is normal! anyway it worked now by change %...% to !...! .

Comment: yeah I see I get blanks with clicking too! clicking aside, as to the %var% odd behaviour and need for setlocal and  !var!  when the var variable is within an IF or FOR. It's mentioned in set /?

Comment: @Mehdi98  yes and that !var! code works when clicked too.  I think I see more of what's going on with the incorrect code, with the blanks and the %var% code.  If you open a new cmd window, then run the broken code, it gives a blank the first time, and the second time it is run, it just echos the value of w from before that for loop, which is the value that the last running left w as.  Because the program with %var%, even though it doesn't echo w correctly, it does set w correctly 'cos the set line doesn't use %var%.

Comment: @Mehdi98 so if you put set w=abcdefg at the top of the broken program it will always echo that.  but if you don't, then it echos the value of w from before that for loop. Clicking it, w is always blank('cos it's like and is running it in a new cmd window). And opening a new cmd window and running it, w is blank the first time it's run but not after. Anyhow, that just explains the behaviour of the broken code. The working code (the one with setlocal and !var!) naturally works whether clicked or executed first or second or whenever! (as you have/would have seen/would see)